# Putty - 0.75-1 Can't open saved sessions after upgrade

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, session, superputty

Upgraded Putty from last version to a new version:
**Release 0.75-1**

Now, one of my saved session: **Server123** is not opening up. It has good amount of SSH tunnels set that I use. I had saved registry backup for Putty, and even tried that, all Putty saved entries came back, but opening the saved session is not working.

**PS**:

1. If I enter the same server entry again, it works! but the existing
   saved entry is not working.
2. There are bunch of servers listed and all have SSH tunnels set, I'm trying to avoid i.e. don't
   want to re-create those saved sessions again and add all SSH Tunnels again.

I don't see anything in putty.log (that you set under `Session > Logging` ) and not getting any errors, session window open on the screen.

Comment: You can export Putty settings and sessions:  https://my.hfcc.edu/students/classes/cis/tutorials/putty-settings#:~:text=To%20export%2C%20run%20RegEdit.exe,registry%20file%20before%20launching%20PuTTY.   I do not know if this will work for you after upgrading.   I am using Putty 0.75 (no -1) and it is the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Martin. Yes, that's the case.

This bug was introduced during a major reorganization of the terminal code between 0.74 and 0.75.

Why is this issue happening!!

**Reason**: Under `Putty > Windows > Colors` if you have "Use System Colors" check-box checked-in, then Windows PuTTY causes a NULL dereference and opening/double clicking on the session in Putty will not do anything (no log file will be created and that session will not open)

**Summary:**
In PuTTY 0.75 **or** 0.75-1, enabling the 'Use system colours' checkbox in the configuration causes PuTTY to dereference a null pointer and crash during terminal window setup.

[image]

**This issue is absent in version**: **0.74**
cd32ef873365a0a478824e1bdea93c39fbf07655

This **issue is present** in version: 0.75 ca9cd983e17e0beb589b07f33d36e2fae3143e38 or 0.75-1 versions

**This issue is fixed in version**: **0.76** 571fa3388d61f3270d958503c62f09669665f6f8 329bdb344c268f91ed726e000028cf52806ef5cb